# How does Chess.com calculate puzzle rating?

Tags: rating, puzzles, chess.com

How does chess.com calculate puzzle rating? I am curious because today, I managed to gain rating while incorrectly solving a puzzle. Could someone help me out? (Also on puzzles that are already rated, not just pending)

Answer (score 3):

According to Chess.com's [How do Puzzle ratings work?](https://support.chess.com/article/2016-how-do-puzzle-ratings-work) you can get +1 point for getting ***pending puzzles*** incorrect as they have not yet received an established rating.

> "About 5% of the puzzles you run into will be new puzzles that have
> not yet been rated. You will never lose points for getting one of
> these Pending puzzles wrong!"

As for how they calculate the Puzzle ratings, these are similar to the playing ratings with a few key differences:

- **Correctly solving a puzzle always increases your puzzle rating** whereas a win against a much lower rated player may not increase your rating. Solving the lowest rated puzzle will at least give you 1 point.
- A new puzzle receives a rating based on the puzzle ratings of those able to solve it. However, after a set amount of time the rating is locked and will not change. Chess.com does have a means to correct the locked rating up or down if needed.

For puzzles with multiple moves, there is a "partial credit" scoring system where you can till receive a net increase in puzzle rating for getting a few moves right even if you missed some at the end of the sequence.

[image: Chess.com image with annotation showing a puzzle is pending.]

Comment: What if I get 2/3 moves correct? I sometimes gain rating on rated puzzles. (For getting them wrong.)

Comment: @MrChessR Updated answer to include this point.

Comment: @MrChessR did this answer your question?